# more entities are getting loaded into one entity , but expected only one .... How to stop unwanted entity loading in Criteria API?

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Hi i'm joining 4 tables(Entities) with root entity , along with 9 optional conditions .
        IPRInterestTypeValue entity have one to many relationship with IPRInterestSubTypeValue,and join type is LAZY . While fetching result root entity by applying conditions expectation is 1 IPRInterestTypeValue  along with 1 child entity (IPRInterestSubTypeValue).if The query generated is excecuted in DB  its giving expected result , but while inspecting  result root entity  its generated some more select queries and more number of child(IPRInterestSubTypeValue) are loaded into root entity.here is my joinig implimentation here reference name for getting and joing are declared seperately  `How to stop unwanted entity loading?`

```
   CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<IPRInterestTypeValue> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(IPRInterestTypeValue.class);
    Root<IPRInterestTypeValue> iprInterestTypeValue = criteriaQuery.from(IPRInterestTypeValue.class);

    Join<IPRInterestTypeValue, IPRInterestPackage> iprinterestPackage = iprInterestTypeValue.join(INTEREST_PACKAGE, JoinType.INNER);

    Join<IPRInterestTypeValue, IPROrgInterestTypeProductType> iprOrgInterestTypeProductType =iprInterestTypeValue.join(INTEREST_TYPE_PRODUCT_TYPE,JoinType.INNER);


    Join<IPRInterestTypeValue, IPRInterestSubTypeValue> iprInterestSubType = iprInterestTypeValue.join(INTEREST_SUBTYPE_VALUES, JoinType.INNER);

    Join<IPRInterestSubTypeValue, IPRInterestRate> iprinterestRate = iprInterestSubType.join(INTEREST_RATES, JoinType.INNER);

   // iprInterestTypeValue.fetch("INTEREST_SUBTYPE_VALUES",JoinType.INNER);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    Expression<Date> validFromDate = iprinterestRate.<Date> get(VALID_FROM);

    Expression<Date> validToDate = iprinterestRate.<Date> get(VALID_TO);

    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(iprinterestPackage.get(ORG_ID), orgId));
    if (null != interestPackageId) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(iprinterestPackage.get(INTEREST_PACKAGE_ID), interestPackageId));
    }
    if (null != interestPackageKey) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(iprinterestPackage.get(INTEREST_PACKAGE_KEY), interestPackageKey));
    }
    if (null != interestSubtypeId) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(iprInterestSubType.get(INTEREST_SUBTYPE_VALUE_ID), interestSubtypeId));
    }
    if (null != interestTypeCode) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(iprOrgInterestTypeProductType.get(INTEREST_TYPE_CODE), interestTypeCode));
    }
    if (null != interestRateStatus) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(iprinterestRate.get(STATUS), interestRateStatus));
    }

    if (searchPeriod != null && String.valueOf(SearchPeriod.CURRENT).equals(searchPeriod)) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(validFromDate, currentDate));
    }

    if (searchPeriod != null && String.valueOf(SearchPeriod.PAST).equals(searchPeriod)) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThan(validToDate, currentDate));
    }

    if (searchPeriod != null && String.valueOf(SearchPeriod.FUTURE).equals(searchPeriod)) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(validFromDate, currentDate));
    }
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and((predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))));
    criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(iprInterestTypeValue.get(INTEREST_TYPE_PRODUCT_TYPE).get(MANDATORY)), criteriaBuilder.asc(iprinterestRate.get(STATUS)));
    List<IPRInterestTypeValue> interestTypeValue = super.getResultListByCriteria(criteriaQuery, pagingElement);
    super.flush();
    return prepareInterestTypeSubTy
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but I think you're confusing two very different things: the result of a query, and the state of an entity. The state of an entity will always be the same, whatever the query you used to get that entity. A query allows doing something like "I want to get all the parents having a son named John". Once you do that, you'll get Harold, who has a son named John. Now if you ask Harold "who are your children?" (i.e. calling harold.getChildren()), Harold will answer "John, Mark and Mary", because those are Harold's children.

Comment: yes i'm agree with you , but when i ask Harold "who are your children name as Mary ?" he is answering John, Mark and Mary all names but need to answer as Mary only . If i excecute that query in DB he is saying only Mary , In My App after this query(Which is giving proper result ) its ok , after that its generating some select queries and putting those list of child in parent collection. Is it the problem of Eager/Lazy fetch in Entities??

Comment: Your comment confirms what I thought. You're still confusing the query, which returns parents (i.e. instances of IPRInterestTypeValue), and the state of the entity (i.e. what is returned by -presumably- value.getSubTypeValues()). You're never asking anywhere "who are your children name as Mary ?". To do that, you would need a query that returns instance of children, i.e. instances of IPRInterestSubTypeValue. You're searching for parents (i.e. instances of IPRInterestTypeValue) who have a child named Mary.

Comment: I'm adding the name condition (i.e "who are your children name as Mary) into predicate list getting the attribute through joining                   if (null != interestSubtypeId) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(iprInterestSubType.get(INTEREST_SUBTYPE_VALUE_ID), interestSubtypeId));
        }) 
here INTEREST_SUBTYPE_VALUE_ID as name condition

Comment: That allows retrieveing all the parents who have a child name "Mary". That doesn't mean they don't have other children. Calling getChildren() on a parent will **always** return all the children of this parent. If you want all the children named Mary of a given parent, you need a query that returns childre: `select child from parent p join p.children child where child.name = 'Mary' and ...`.